# Set status bar orientation in iOS 6.0

Tags: ipad, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation, uiapplication, uistatusbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setStatusBarOrientation:animated: not working in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563954/setstatusbarorientationanimated-not-working-in-ios-6)

In iOS 6.0, as AppDelegate by default extends UIRepsonder and not UIApplication there is no global sharedApplication object. Am I missing anything? I am trying to set status bar orientation using following and it doesn't seem to work anymore. I tested it on iOS 6.0 simulator. I know you can set status bar tint color from the plist settings but can anyone please tell me how to set status bar orientation programmatically in iOS 6.0?

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed this. It works only if I have following methods implemented in my rootViewController.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's not working help me dude..

Comment: what's not working? It's implementation again changed in iOS 7.0. You will find plenty of discussion on SO on it.